# Julia / Graphs.jl : creating graph using graph() and arguments

Tags: indexing, graph, julia

I am trying to get subgraph from graph in Julia using Graphs.jl module.
I have graph and i store his vertices and edges to list and then my algorithm moves trough this list and remove nodes and edges which are not part of new subgraph. To this part everything works correctly, after whole algorithm all that remains is array **sub_vertices** **type: Graphs.ExVertex[]** and array **sub_edges** **type: Graphs.ExEdge{Graphs.ExVertex}[]**.

At the end of whole function I wanto to create subgraph so I use:

```
sub_g = graph(sub_vertices, sub_edges, is_directed=false)
```

But i get **Bounds() error**.
Any idea ? All I know that problem is in edges.

I tried to run:

```
sub_g = graph(sub_vertices, Graphs.ExEdge{Graphs.ExVertex}[], is_directed=false)
```

And it runs ok. It creates graph with vertices given by array **sub_vertices**. Problem occurs when adding edges with **sub_edges**.

**Additional info:**
Vertices and Edges are exact copies from original graph. That means attributes like index, label, ... are same as in original graph. I thought that maybe indexes of vertices will be problem but It is not because when i run,

```
sub_g = graph(sub_vertices, Graphs.ExEdge{Graphs.ExVertex}[], is_directed=false)
```

it runs OK. And after printing the vertices they have indexes for example 1,3,5 but it seems ok. So i do not know why edges gives bounds error.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `Graphs.jl`, or would you be open to a `LightGraphs.jl` solution?

Comment: Yes there is but i found another solution. This is problem,cause by indexes and I think  that solution even does not exist.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you post your solution as an answer, in case people have the same problem in the future?

Comment: It is not solution for how to write this construction method properly but solution or I would say workaround for how to get subgraph from graph easily. I will post it as soon as i arrive home :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to use the graph constructor to get a subgraph. I'm not too familiar with *Graphs.jl* but I have worked with graphs in Julia.

The constructor probably assigns new indices to *sub_vertices*. So if *sub_vertices* is **[5,6,9]**, for example, the new graph will still use **[1,2,3]**. If your edge list was **[5=>6, 6=>9, 9=>5]**, you'll notice that none of the edges are valid because the subgraph only has vertices **[1,2,3]**.

I would suggest you to use a dedicated *subgraph* method to accomplish what you're trying to do, in two stages:

1. First, compute a subgraph using the *sub_edges* you've isolated.
2. Next, compute a subgraph using the *sub_vertices*.

[Graft.jl](https://github.com/pranavtbhat/Graft.jl) has a method that lets you do both at once:

```
  julia> using Graft

  julia> g = completegraph(10)
         Graph(10 vertices, 90 edges, Symbol[] vertex properties, Symbol[] edge properties)

  julia> sg = subgraph(g, [5,6,9], [5=>6, 6=>9, 9=>5])
         Graph(3 vertices, 3 edges, Symbol[] vertex properties, Symbol[] edge properties)

  julia> vertices(sg)
         1:3

  julia> edges(sg)
         3-element Graft.EdgeIter:
            1=>2
            2=>3
            3=>1
```

Or if you want the vertices to retain their original labels

```
  julia> g = completegraph(10)
         Graph(10 vertices, 90 edges, Symbol[] vertex properties, Symbol[] edge properties)

  julia> setlabel!(g, collect(1:10)) # Label the vertices

  julia> sg = subgraph(g, [5,6,9], [5=>6, 6=>9, 9=>5])
         Graph(3 vertices, 3 edges, Symbol[] vertex properties, Symbol[] edge properties)

  julia> encode(sg)
         3-element Array{Int64,1}:
            5
            6
            9

  julia> encode(sg, edges(sg))
         3-element Array{Pair{Int64,Int64},1}:
            5=>6
            6=>9
            9=>5
```